# App to lock the phone “right now”

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-lock

I configure my devices to only turn off the screen after a couple of minutes, and only lock themselves several minutes after (so I can quickly turn on the screen without needing to unlock them all the time), for example when outside walking for geocaching.

On Android, I have an application on my home screen which forces locking the phone (i.e. turns off the screen *and* makes it so that it requires the PIN when turned on again), which makes this scenario useful/secure. I would call this app when I want to turn off the device without needing to turn it on soon.

Which app do I need to install on iOS to achieve the same effect? (iPhone SE, iOS 13)

Answer (score 4):

[[Apple] - Use Emergency SOS on your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208076):

> Press and hold the side button and one of the Volume buttons until the Emergency SOS slider appears.

[image]

This locks the screen and requires a pin:

> If you use the Emergency SOS shortcut, you need to enter your passcode to re-enable Touch ID, even if you don't complete a call to emergency services.

If that doesn't work ([iPhone 7 and earlier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone#History_and_availability)):

> Rapidly press the side (or top) button five times.

Note that you may want to turn off "Auto Call", to avoid accidentally calling emergency services. This can be done in the "Emergency SOS" settings.

[image]

Comment: Hrm. In my case (iPhone SE) it’s _very_ rapidly clicking the on/off button five times (I needed two tries to get it), *and* you **must** turn off Auto-Call first. I’m upvoting this answer, because technically, it’s a valid one, but I’m scared every time I use it, so I’ll wait for a better way to actually accept as good answer to the problem. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @mirabilos edited - let me know if there are any other improvements I can make. 1. I believe Auto Call is off by default, but still worth mentioning. 2. I'm surprised that the SE is considered iPhone 7 or earlier, as I deduced that you have the 2nd gen SE due to your iOS version - which came out after iPhone 7. 3. I personally have no concern using this, as it requires explicitly calling - but of course, that's subjective.

Comment: Sorry, no, I have the 2016 iPhone SE, “the oldest iPhone to run iOS 13” according to Wikipedia. Thanks!

Comment: Ah I misread that table, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

You can use AssistiveTouch (Settings > General > Accessibility) where a tiny bubble floats on the screen. You can set it such that holding it locks the phone, or double-tapping it does it, or single tap > tapping the "Lock Screen" icon does it.

> The menu gives you access to functions that would otherwise be controlled by pressing physical buttons or moving the device. Here's some of what you can do: 
> Activate the Accessibility Shortcut 
> Lock the screen
> Adjust the volume

https://support.apple.com/HT202658

Comment: Unfortunately not, that merely turns off the screen but does not lock it.

Comment: @mirabilos looking at the options available for single tap shows “lock screen”...

Comment: @SolarMike and that precisely **does _not_** lock the screen, only turn it off. I tried.